# How to get number of highest elements in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Delhi
            [1] => Delhi
            [2] => Delhi
            [3] => Delhi
            [4] => Delhi
            [5] => Delhi
            [6] => Bengaluru
            [7] => Bengaluru
            [8] => Jaipur
            [9] => Arezzo
            [10] => Jaipur
            [11] => Hyderabad
            [12] => West Palm Beach
        )
```

and  I want the result as the highest numbers of elements in array like as

```
delhi = 6
bangaluru = 2
jaipur = 2
arezzo = 1
hyderabad = 1
west palm beach = 1
```

Comment: yes got my answer. Thanks @ggorlen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$data= array_count_values($array)`

[PHP Manaul](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)